# Get Task for QueueBackgroundWorkItem

Tags: .net-core

I have a controller:

```
private IBackgroundTaskQueue _queue;

[HttpPost("Add")]
public async Task<ActionResult<long>> Add([FromForm] long data)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    return Calc(data);
                });
}

private ActionResult<long> Calc(long data)
{
    return new ObjectResult(data);
}
```

How to change  implementation to use IBackgroundTaskQueue from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

to return task handler in controller?

```
return await _queue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(clt => Calc(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

`QueueBackgroundWorkItem` in that example is for queueing work to a background worker to do *after* your controller action returns its response.

However, your example needs to return a result (the `long`). So it doesn't make sense to use this kind of queue in your example.

On a side note, you should avoid `Task.Run` on ASP.NET; you can just call the method directly instead:

```
[HttpPost("Add")]
public ActionResult<long> Add([FromForm] long data)
{
  return Calc(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to return the task.

```
Task<BaseTask> Dequeue();
```

I put on github some first version of working solution. The solution can be extended with information on progress, cancellation or improve.

https://github.com/lsmolinski/MonitoredQueueBackgroundWorkItem